# Non-English characters do not get properly loaded at \AtBeginDocument

Tags: fonts, xetex

Please see this MWE given below which uses [Bengali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengali_language) as its main font. The macro `\executefirst` is being executed twice. Once, via `\AtBeginDocument`, and again directly on the next page. But the results of execution are different when comes
the issue of rendering of the non-English characters.

```
\documentclass{article}

% For bilingual document
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% Bangla
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontbf[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifonttt[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontsf[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{SolaimanLipi}

\setotherlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

% Times New Roman used
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

\def\executefirst{
  % Both of these are supposed to use the non-English font
  English Text in Main non-English Font
  
  বাংলা লেখা

  % The following will use the English font

  \begin{english}
    English Text in Second (English) Font
  \end{english}}                               

\AtBeginDocument{\executefirst}

\begin{document}

Page 1

\clearpage
\executefirst

Page 2

\end{document}
```

However, as already mentioned above, the results of the two executions are different.

---

From the first execution, *only* the English characters (both in the non-English main font and in (second) English font) are being displayed. The non-English texts are missing.

[image]

---

However, the second direct execution renders all the characters correctly.

[image]

---

This is strange. `\AtBeginDocument` is supposed to load all the font tables correctly before execution of any code.

> **`\AtBeginDocument`**
>
> Synopsis:
>
> `\AtBeginDocument{code}` Save code and execute it when `\begin{document}`
> is executed, at the very end of the preamble. The code is executed
> after the font selection tables have been set up, so the normal font
> for the document is the current font. However, the code is executed as
> part of the preamble so you cannot do any typesetting with it.

I am using the `xelatex` which came with Ubuntu 21.04.

The non-English font mentioned can be downloaded from [here.](https://www.omicronlab.com/download/fonts/SolaimanLipi_20-04-07.ttf))

Comment: I never tried it, but the help you cited says explicitly that you shouldn't typeset anything in the AtBeginDocument hook...

Comment: @Rmano The quote is from here, http://latexref.xyz/_005cAtBeginDocument.html. Don't find anything as you mentioned. Am I missing something?

Comment: It says "However, the code is executed as part of the preamble so you cannot do any typesetting with it."...

Comment: check the documentation lthooks-doc.pdf (assuming that you have a current latex): it explicitly say that this hook should not be used for typesetting, use `\AddToHook{begindocument/end}{...}` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work with `\AtBeginDocument` as the language is still english. polyglossia selects the main language later.

So you could get it working by forcing bengali in your command

```
\newcommand\executefirst{\selectlanguage{bengali}....
```

But as lthooks-doc.pdf says about the `begindocument` hook which is used with  `\AtBeginDocument`:

> The hook should not be used to add material for typesetting as we are still in LATEX’s initialization phase and not in the document body.

Instead use (with a current LaTeX, with older tex system, use the commands from etoolbox) the `begindocument/end` hook:

```
  \AddToHook{begindocument/end}{\executefirst}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks. Actually, the code was part of an old (home-cooked) style file that I tried to use after a gap of a couple of years. But this failed to produce the intended results that were fine at that time. Thank again.